# Spring Cloud config client not picking values from Config server

Tags: spring-cloud, configserver, spring-cloud-config-server

> My Config client is not picking the property values from  config
>   server.

```
http://localhost:8888/customer_service/default
```

Above Config server endpoint is returning proper values for Config client,

```
{
    "name": "customer_service",
    "profiles": [
        "default"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "c7648db5662dc65aeaad9c91abbf58b41010be7c",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://github.com/prasadrpm/MicroService_config.git/customer_service.properties",
            "source": {
                "customer.config.location": "XXXX",
                "customer.config.name": "YYYY"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Config client bootstrap.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=customer_service

spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.name=config_server
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

Config client Log

```
2020-04-10 16:47:00.725  INFO 14976 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2020-04-10 16:47:03.267  INFO 14976 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=config_server, profiles=[default], label=null, version=c7648db5662dc65aeaad9c91abbf58b41010be7c, state=null
2020-04-10 16:47:03.269  INFO 14976 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}]
2020-04-10 16:47:03.280  INFO 14976 --- [           main] com.customer.CustomerServiceApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
...
2020-04-10 16:47:05.164  INFO 14976 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1860 ms
2020-04-10 16:47:05.549  WARN 14976 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'customer.config.location' in value "${customer.config.location}"
2020-04-10 16:47:05.552  INFO 14976 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-04-10 16:47:05.577  INFO 14976 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-10 16:47:05.595 ERROR 14976 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'customer.config.location' in value "${customer.config.location}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: i fixed my problem in config server i made, spring.application.name and my properties name is same, then my files loaded into config client, ex  spring.application.name = elconfigserver, file name elconfigserver.properties and if not working add bootstrap dependency in client service and try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL that returns you correct properties/configuration is: `localhost:8888/customer_service/default`

Client application is querying for properties based on following data:

```
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=config_server, profiles=[default], label=null, version=c7648db5662dc65aeaad9c91abbf58b41010be7c, state=null
b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}]
com.customer.CustomerServiceApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
...
```

So, effectively, client application is calling:

```
localhost:8888/config_server/default
```

So, there are two solutions:

- delete `spring.cloud.config.name=config_server` property in bootstrap.properties, and your application should be able to fetch properties.
- update value of `spring.cloud.config.name` to `customer_service` service. But if you do not provide `spring.cloud.config.name` explicitly, then client will use `spring.application.name` as the default value for `spring.cloud.config.name`.

Answer (score 0):

What annotation you had used here?
It can be easily retrieved like this.

```
@Value("${customer.config.location}")
    private String someOtherProperty;
```

and it is not needed

> spring.cloud.config.name=config_server

Comment: i am just using exact same annotation.
@Value("${customer.config.location}")
     private String location;

Comment: @Arunprasad can you share the snippet of the controller where you are trying to retrieve it?